# Watir Selenium see if ajax request made

Tags: ajax, selenium, watir

Is there any way in Watir to check if a ajax call is made?
I mean when testing manually the tester would open Firebug or an equivalent program and check under the network tab and see that the request appears there.
How could this be automated using Watir?

Comment: For jQuery, there is a `jQuery.active` property that you could check. I am not sure if similar would be available in other frameworks.

Comment: Yes @JustinKo but that is a property tells you if there are any ajax requests running. I need to be able to identify individual requests by the names of the scripts they target. I am not interested if all the ajax requests have been completed I am interested if a request to a particular url has been made.